# How can I get the product of for loop values?

Tags: python, math

This function is asking the user for a string, which the given string will be on Counter function and will factorize the counted character duplicates.

How can I get the product of the factorial counted character duplicates in for loop?

my code looks like this

```
def pwrw():
    word = input("Word: ")
    n = len(word)
    fn = math.factorial(n)
    x = Counter(word)
    for j in x.values():
        no = math.factorial(j)
        print(numpy.prod(no))
```

example of input is *tallahassee*.

therefore the Counter method would return a dictionary which specify how many did the word repeat which in my case is

*{'a': 3, 'l': 2, 's': 2, 'e': 2, 't': 1, 'h': 1}*

i used for loop to return only the values of the dictionary and I use math.factorial to factorize each values of the *tallahassee* dictionary.

so if I print the no variable only, the output will be like this.
*1
6
2
1
2
2*

if you are wondering, I am making a function that follows the formula of permutation with repetition.

Comment: Could you please specify what `x.values()` returns or add `Counter` source code?

Comment: Could you please show us some input and output examples?

Comment: `fn` is unused. What do you currently have is the product of a single number. If you want the product of multiple numbers, use `product=1; for ...: product *= no` and print it after the loop

Comment: I already edit it for examples, fn will be use after I am done with the current bug. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas Weller noticed in the comments, `fn` is unused, so it can be removed. `n` is also used, you can safely delete it.

To get product of all factorials, I would suggest three options:

1. Create a variable outside the loop and on each iteration multiply it by factorial.

```
def pwrw():
    word = input("Word: ")
    x = Counter(word)
    result = 1
    for j in x.values():
        result *= math.factorial(j)
    print(result)
```

2. Store all factorials in the array and then call `numpy.prod` for this array:

```
def pwrw():
    word = input("Word: ")
    x = Counter(word)
    factorials = []
    for j in x.values():
        factorials.append(math.factorial(j))
    print(numpy.prod(factorials))
```

3. Inline `factorial` array creation

```
def pwrw():
    word = input("Word: ")
    x = Counter(word)
    result = numpy.prod([math.factorial(y) for y in x.values()])
    print(result)
```